# Problem with the path in vue/vuex import plugins/modules or some nginx config

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vuex

I am working on a vue project. I have this and it works well on my localhost:

```
import pluginSubscription from '/resources/js/store/modules/frontend/plugin/action/subscription'
```

When I upload it to nginx server (E.g. https://testing.com. ), this line does not work because the path is wrong. It will work if I edit it to:

```
import pluginSubscription from '/home/test/public_html/resources/js/store/modules/frontend/plugin/action/subscription'
```

(Add absolute path /home/test/public_html/)

My question is: I don't know how to fix this if I only use the relative path instead absolute path (/home/test/...). This is a miss from nginx config?

Please advise.

Comment: What is the path of the file you put import code?

Comment: It's in /resources/js/components/...

Comment: So the file is in the components folder. In this case, import route should be "../store/modules/...